# Is there a windows event that can tell if presentation mode is turned on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was referring to the list of events documented on this link, but can't find one for presentation mode:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735621(v%3dws.10)

Comment: The link you posted is for the WUA Updates Installer, which doesn't have anything to do with anything but updates installation. It has to do with updating the Windows Update Agent. What does it have to do with *presentation mode*?

Comment: How about this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754424(v%3dws.10)

Comment: That has to do with the Event Viewer events, not anything to do with code. Are you just randomly grabbing links from Microsoft that contain the word *event*?

Comment: No, I need to query the event logs and see if certain events got fired. So referencing the list of events and trying to find one for presentation mode

Comment: So put your PC in presentation mode, exit from presentation mode, and check your event viewer to see what was recorded.